# $G$ finite abelian, $\exists H < G : |G/H|$ is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. Is there a subgroup $H < G $ s.t. the quotient $ G/H$ has prime order?

Comment: No, $G = \{e\}$. But otherwise, yes, for nontrivial finite abelian $G$ such a subgroup always exists.

Comment: The answer is clearly yes if $|G|>1$ by the structure theory of finite abelian groups. The more interesting question is how low-tech of a way there is to see this.

Comment: @anon One could use Cauchy's theorem (which is very easy to prove for Abelian groups) to strip away a prime at a time.

Comment: @anon: It is easy: just take an arbitrary quotient and apply induction.

Comment: @anon Induction on the order is fairly low-tech, isn't it? If $\lvert G\rvert$ isn't prime, find any proper subgroup $H_0$, $G/H_0$ has a subgroup of prime index. Lift back.

Comment: Direct it at the OP guys, not me!

Comment: @anon The OP is notified anyway, so why waste an `@`?

Comment: Yes I see it, if you bother to expand the argument just a little and post an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G \neq 1$, let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$. Such an $M$ exists since $G$ is finite. Then, $G/M$ is a finite group with exactly two subgroups by the correspondence theorem.

Answer (score 4):

The [Classification Theorem for finite abelian groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group) states that any finite abelian group is isomorphic to $$G:=\mathbb{Z}_{q_1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q_2} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{q_t}$$ where $q_i$ is a prime power for all $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,t\}$.

If the group is non-trivial, then $q_1 \geq 1$, so $G$ has a subgroup $$H:=\langle p \rangle \times \mathbb{Z}_{q_2} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{q_t}$$ where $p$ is the prime dividing $q_1$, and $\langle p \rangle$ is the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{q_1}$ generated by $p$.

We observe that $H$ is [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup) in $G$, since $G$ is abelian, so $G/H$ is a group (a [quotient group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group)).

The underlying set of $G/H$ is $$\{(i,\overbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}^{t-1})+H:0 \leq i \leq p-1\}$$ which has size $p$.

Answer (score 2):

Moreover, for every divisor $m||G|$ there is $H<G$ such that $|G/H|=m$.